# Rspec assigns equivalent in unit test/minitest

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, sinatra, minitest

Is there rspec `assigns` equivalent in `MiniTest::Test`? If not how can I check the instant controller instant variable in tests. I am using sinatra

Comment: Have you seen http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html ?

Answer (score 1):

The [`assigns`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/TestProcess.html#method-i-assigns) method comes from Rails, not RSpec or Minitest. It works just the same.

The following example is from the [Rails Testing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers):

```
class PostsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:posts)
  end
end
```